# Can't find installed kernel version

Tags: kernel

I'm trying to uninstall some kernel versions to free up space in `/boot`. I did `kernelver=$(uname -r | sed -r 's/-[a-z]+//'); dpkg -l linux-{image,headers}-"[0-9]*" | awk '/ii/{print $2}'` to find which kernel versions are installed and got

```
linux-headers-3.13.0-87
linux-headers-3.13.0-87-generic
linux-headers-3.13.0-91
linux-headers-3.13.0-91-generic
linux-headers-3.13.0-92
linux-headers-3.13.0-92-generic
linux-headers-4.2.0-27
linux-headers-4.2.0-27-generic
linux-headers-4.2.0-34
linux-headers-4.2.0-34-generic
linux-headers-4.2.0-36
linux-headers-4.2.0-36-generic
linux-headers-4.2.0-41
linux-headers-4.2.0-41-generic
linux-headers-4.2.0-42
linux-headers-4.2.0-42-generic
linux-image-4.2.0-36-generic
linux-image-4.2.0-41-generic
linux-image-4.2.0-42-generic
```

Then I did `ls /boot` and got:

```
abi-4.2.0-35-generic                  lost+found
abi-4.2.0-36-generic                  memtest86+.bin
abi-4.2.0-41-generic                  memtest86+.elf
abi-4.2.0-42-generic                  memtest86+_multiboot.bin
config-4.2.0-35-generic               System.map-4.2.0-35-generic
config-4.2.0-36-generic               System.map-4.2.0-36-generic
config-4.2.0-41-generic               System.map-4.2.0-41-generic
config-4.2.0-42-generic               System.map-4.2.0-42-generic
efi                                   vmlinuz-4.2.0-35-generic
grub                                  vmlinuz-4.2.0-35-generic.efi.signed
initrd.img-4.2.0-35-generic           vmlinuz-4.2.0-36-generic
initrd.img-4.2.0-35-generic.old-dkms  vmlinuz-4.2.0-36-generic.efi.signed
initrd.img-4.2.0-36-generic           vmlinuz-4.2.0-41-generic
initrd.img-4.2.0-41-generic           vmlinuz-4.2.0-41-generic.efi.signed
initrd.img-4.2.0-41-generic.old-dkms  vmlinuz-4.2.0-42-generic
initrd.img-4.2.0-42-generic           vmlinuz-4.2.0-42-generic.efi.signed
initrd.img-4.2.0-42-generic.old-dkms
```

What's going on here?

Comment: Not sure what your actual question is here - did you look at the value of `$kernelver`? Or run `uname -r` on its own instead of capturing the command output.

Comment: Yep, it's `4.2.0-35`. The question is why do I have, for example, kernel 3.13.0-87 installed and yet can't see its files in `/boot`.

Comment: Those are kernel *header* packages - AFAIK they're only used for building kernel modules (most likely drivers that you have installed using [dkms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Kernel_Module_Support) - since you no longer have the actual kernel packages corresponding to those headers, they would usually be removed by apt's `autoremove` I think.

Comment: Hmmm...unfortunately I `autoremove` fails as `/boot` only has 415k free. How can I remove these and free up space on `/boot`?